# countdown timer target date hidden input field javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

My hidden input field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="expire_date" value="2015-10-31 00:00:00">
```

I have product offer expire date like this I want countdown timer from now time

dates, hours, Minutes in seperate `<div>` s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use countdownTimer jquery library for that. I guide you how to do that. First download jquery.countdownTimer.js and jquery.countdownTimer.css files.

html should be as follows.

```
<!-- link java script and css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.countdownTimer.css" />

<input type="hidden" id="exp" name="expire_date" value="2015-10-31 00:00:00">
<div id="countdowntimer"><span id="future_date"><span></div>
```

Javascript should be something like following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var expier= $("#exp").val();
    expier = expier.replace("-", "/");
    $("#future_date").countdowntimer({
        dateAndTime : expier,
    size : "lg",
        regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})",
            regexpReplaceWith: "$1<sup>days</sup> / $2<sup>hours</sup> / $3<sup>minutes</sup> / $4<sup>seconds</sup>"
    });
});
</script>
```

There are demos on the following url and you can also download all the required files with demo from that.
http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/